# Query with split in where clause

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to craft a Google Sheets query that outputs rows based on the left half of a split.

I'm using this in an employee status tracking sheet where my overview tab shows the last status update taken from the data tab (eventually)

This is what the overview tab will eventually look like. Note the number to the left of the employee name, I'm using this like an index.

[image: https://screenshot.click/4229-03-12-19-je4iu.jpg]

This is where the data lives, there is an employee and multiple status updates. Note the numbers being used here as well. Each status update starts with the employee number "1" followed by a "-" then an incremental number.

[image: https://screenshot.click/4229-03-12-19-k2kh7.jpg]

It's easy enough to output all of the status updates, or a single status update, where I'm stuck is how to output only the updates that match the employee number.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({DataRange,to_text(DataRange)},"Select Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col2 ='"&"1-1"&"'",0))
```

[image: https://screenshot.click/4229-03-12-19-l0clw.jpg]

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? 
-- or any suggestions for tacking this type of sheet in a different way?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this - surely all the rows under the heading Johnny Tables will relate only to the employee called Johnny Tables? Can you show how it would look with some data for another employee added plz, or share an anonymised version of your sheet as suggested by @Player0 ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({DataRange, TO_TEXT(DataRange)},
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4 where Col2 ='1-1'", 0))
```

and make sure that `1-1` is formatted as **Plain text** not Date